# How to rotate SVG text with css

Tags: javascript, css, svg, c3.js

I am using c3.js to produce a chart. the problem is that the I cannot change the position of text elements on xgrid. I would like them to be horizontal. But when ever I try to use rotate the elements go outside of svg. How can I place then exactly where they are but make them horizontal

js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yrzxj3x2/7/

here is the css that I have tried for complete code see js fiddle

```
.xLineLable text{
  font-size: 12px;
}
.c3-grid text {
    fill: #000;
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
```

Comment: use transform-origin perhaps

Comment: The `transform` attribute on the SVG element itself appears to override any CSS you assign to it. Unfortunately, [I don't see any way to rotate the text using c3.js](http://c3js.org/reference.html#grid-x-lines). Assigning horizontal text to a vertical line is ambiguous anyway, and I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: you may need to reset display so it takes transform, but weird behavior in FF http://jsfiddle.net/yrzxj3x2/19/

Comment: @GCyrillus You're just used to the weird (and incorrect per spec) behaviour of Chrome ;-)

Answer (score 15):

You can rotate text in horizontal by add following css.

```
.c3-grid text {
    fill: #000;
    transform:rotate(0deg) translate(266px, 0px);
  }
```

If you want to add more lines then you should increase value manually.

You can also give position like:

```
 x: {
    lines: [
      {value: "2016-01-08", text: "Want to rorate this text in 180 degrees",
      class: "xLineLable", position: "outer-middle"}


    ]
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yrzxj3x2/23/)**

**Edit:**

If you want horizontal line then why you don't add to ygrid.

```
 grid: {
     y: {
        lines: [
                {value: 50,text: "Want to rorate this text in 180 degrees",
      class: "xLineLable", position: "middle"},

            ]
     },
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yrzxj3x2/31/)**

Comment: but then when I add more lines to the chart there text does not show as well... http://jsfiddle.net/yrzxj3x2/26/

Answer (score 3):

So the text in your fiddle says to rotate it 180 degrees...

I did that here:

```
transform: translate(90px, 230px) rotate(90deg) !important;
```

I also made it horizontal like you wanted and moved it down to a readable place:

```
 transform: translate(295px, 115px);
```

You can move the x and y coordinates to put it back up higher if you want. It looks like the grid elements using positions. Not sure what that code looks like.

Comment: This is one of those **annoying** cases where you need 4 similar, but browser specific lines in your css, details here   https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/  the basic form is **svg{transform: rotate(45deg); }**

Comment: If you're talking about browser prefixes, you can use auto-prefixer sublime plugin to add those lines for you and im sure a lot of other tools that autocomplete that for you as well.